# incorrect credentials and non working installation of Vagrant-Reddit

Tags: linux, git, vagrant, virtual-machine, reddit

I was interested in working with a local version of reddit (cause its cool) and I cant seem to get it running. I got the code from https://github.com/reddit/reddit-vagrant And I am running the last OS X prior to yosemite. After installation, the VM is up with the server (pingable) but unreachable through browser. When the VM on VirtualBox is started manually then I am asked for username and password, but the ones provided on git are not granting me access (incorrect login)
Any help is appreciated, can try to provide any necessary information :)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem. It appears that the defaults for VirtualBox VMs are:

username: `vagrant`

password: `vagrant`